# Awk doesnt work with the first line

Tags: bash, awk

Good day to everyone.

Could you, please, help me with some of my file preparation problem:

I have a file:

```
2:1 3:1 4:2 5:1 7:2 34:1 37:3 ...
4:2 6:1 8:1 23:1 25:2 30:1 ...
```

I would like to get:

```
20002:1 20003:1 20004:2 20005:1 20007:2 20034:1 20037:3 ... 
20004:2 20006:1 20008:1 20023:1 20025:2 20030:1 ...
```

I tried:

```
awk '{FS=":"; RS=" "; OFS=":"; ORS=" "}{$1=$1+20000; print $0}'
```

But it works only partially: it doesnt work with the first line, giving `20002:1:3:1:4:2..`, and doesn't work with the first element of each line, giving `4:2 20006:1 20008:1 ...`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this (GNU awk only for RT)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":";RS="[[:space:]]"}{ORS=RT;$1=$1+20000; print $0}' file

20002:1 20003:1 20004:2 20005:1 20007:2 20034:1 20037:3
20004:2 20006:1 20008:1 20023:1 20025:2 20030:1
```

Explanation

```
BEGIN{
#Only run at start of script
FS=OFS=":"
#Set input and output field separator to :
RS="[[:space:]]"
#Set the record separator to any space character e.g `\n` `\t` or  ` `
}


{ORS=RT
#Set the output record separator to whatever was captured by the input one, i.e keep newline space or tab in the right places
$1+=20000; print
#Do your math and print, note that `+=` is shorthand for adding to the current value, 
#and also that print can be used on it's own as by default it prints $0(you can also use 1 
#at the end of the script as this evaluates to true and the default action if no block
#is defined is to print the current line)
}'
```

Comment: @EdMorton I know, but as OP had already provided that code, and it does work(even if not in the most simple way), then i though it would be best to leave it.

Comment: @EdMorton I thought the benefit was not explaining too much and only explaining the parts which would cause it not to work, not the parts which don't look as nice. I will edit though.

Comment: @EdMorton Maybe, they're in there now anyway. Maybe i was just being a bit lazy.

Answer (score 2):

In case of not having GNU awk as required by @123's more elegant solution:

```
$ awk -F"[: ]+" '{for(i=1;i<NF;i+=2){$i+=20000; printf "%s:%s ",$i,$(i+1)} print ""}' cs.txt

20002:1 20003:1 20004:2 20005:1 20007:2 20034:1 20037:3 
20004:2 20006:1 20008:1 20023:1 20025:2 20030:1
```